# select statement return a section of result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

ex:

```
 @productName varchar(50),
    @pageStart int,
    @pageEnd int,
    @result varchar(MAX)

    set @result = select * from products where productName like '%@productName%' 

    return select from @result where section between @pageStrat to  @pageEnd
```

This is How i imagine it ,if this correct? or there is one statement can do the result

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I'm not expert in SP ,i tried but it's gave me errors.

Comment: But what errors to begin with? So we aren't guessing and have some real info. Also, and most important, is the question just about syntax or about a specific query? MySql or SQL Server? Both are somewhat different

Comment: It's about specific query in SQL SERVER ,I tried the code below and it's work fine now .
thank yu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @productName varchar(50),
    @pageStart int,
    @pageEnd int,
    @result varchar(MAX)

select  *  from (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) as row from products where 
productName like @productName) a where a.row between @pageStart and @pageEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
'%@productName%'
```

with

```
'%' + @productName + '%'
```

You are looking for strings that contain the literal "@productName" and I don't think that's what you wanted. Also:

```
between @pageStrat to  @pageEnd
```

should be

```
between @pageStart and @pageEnd
```

note the misspelled @pageStart and the "to" instead of "and" in your version.